# httpd error when adding php5 module to Apache

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I am trying to install the php5 64bits version in my apache 2.4 server.
I added the following code to my httpd file:

```
#PHP
LoadModule php5_module C:/php/php5phpdbg.dll
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir C:/php
```

The server is showing an error message when I restart it. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround the file paths with double quotes:

```
#PHP
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5phpdbg.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

Comment: Adding them or letting them is the same. I tried adding them. This doesent work

Comment: The error message is: The requested operation has failed